# How can i save the last SSH logins (positive attempts) in a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, ssh, raspberry-pi

I know that the SSH-Logins are already saved but i have to access those Logs from somewhere else.
Im using a Raspberry Pi with the Raspberry NOOB. On that Raspberry i run many things and i want all the accepted SSH-Logins to be saved in a database like this:

```
     From    | User  | Time  | date
<external IP>| admin | 12:33 | 21.09.2020
```

Because i want to show the accepted Login attempts on a Website.
And if it is possible i want to show the current active SSH-Connections to in realtime.
The Webserver will run on my own Raspberry Pi.

Thanks for Reading and Helping :)

Comment: i don't think it's a good idea. reading such information from the auth.log would be the best solution

Comment: what would you suggest?

Comment: just a cron job that does grep /var/log/auth.log and saves the result somewhere. then your script reads and displays it